# Use overflow hidden to make content not wrap

Tags: css, overflow, nowrap

I want this :

[image]

But I get this :

[image]

Using this to style the containing div :

```
.option {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:10%;
}
```

The rest is <strike>nothing</strike> here : http://jsfiddle.net/n2LtN/

What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using display:`inline-block` instead of `display:inline`, without `floating` :

```
span, input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /*That's for IE*/
    *zoom:1; /*That's for IE*/
    width:auto;
}
```

See the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/n2LtN/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left` from  `span, input[type="checkbox"]`

You should read up on how float works.

Comment: Okay. I'm trying http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/, http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/, and http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa010107.htm can you recommend anything else that helps?

Comment: @CrisStringfellow Your floating could work too but you'll need a proper width, a clearfix and try using `list elements` (`<li>`) instead of `spans`. I prefer inline-block, it's so easy to use !

Comment: @soyuka Yes inline block is really good. I just learned at http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats  you can only float block elements, not inlines.

Comment: Floated elements stack to the right (or left) of each other, but will wrap if there is no space left in the container, even if you disallow line breaks in text.